# Google Cloud Storage ignoring Content-Disposition: inline

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to make available an internal HTML report to my team without making it publicly accessible. So I uploaded the HTML as an object in a GCS bucket. But when I send people the link to the object

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/our_bucket/path/to/report.html
```

Instead of rendering the HTML, it downloads it. I tried editing the object metadata on the Content-Disposition header, as instructed [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata).

```
gsutil setmeta -h 'Content-Disposition:inline' gs://our_bucket/path/to/report.html
```

I have verified that it set the value in the web console. But, it still doesn't show the file inline in Chrome (or Safari), it just downloads it. The response headers do not include `Content-Disposition:inline` either. It seems to have saved my metadata but is ignoring it. **How can I display my HTML in the browser without downloading to disk first?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my error. It's not enough to set `Content-Disposition:inline`. I also had to set `Content-Type:text/html`.